# grouping customer by start and end date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have df:

```
Product_Name  Customer    Start_Date  End_Date    Period
      LP    abc           29-Oct-16 3-Nov-16    Monthly
      LP    abc           2-Nov-16  8-Jan-17    Monthly
      LP    abc           5-Dec-16  31-Aug-17   Monthly
      LP    abc           7-Jan-17  16-Jun-17   Monthly
      LP    abc           1-Sep-17  30-Mar-18   Monthly
      LP    abc           17-Oct-17 31-Dec-17   Monthly
      LP    abc           20-Oct-18 31-Aug-19   Monthly
      LP    abc            1-Sep-19 27-Oct-20   Monthly
      LP    abc           28-Oct-20 31-Aug-21   Monthly
      LP    abc            1-Sep-21 9-Mar-22    Monthly
      LP    xyz            7-Sep-15 31-Aug-16   Monthly
      LP    xyz            1-Sep-16 14-Oct-16   Monthly
      LP    xyz           20-Oct-16 31-Aug-17   Monthly
      LP    xyz            1-Sep-17 31-Aug-18   Monthly
      LP    xyz           20-Oct-17 31-Aug-18   Annual
      LP    xyz            1-Sep-18 22-Oct-18   Annual
      LP    xyz            1-Sep-18 31-Aug-19   Monthly
      LP    xyz            1-Sep-19 27-Oct-20   Monthly
      LP    xyz           28-Oct-20 31-Aug-21   Monthly
      LP    xyz            1-Sep-21 9-Mar-22    Monthly
```

I want to take consecutive dates (as in one date before, one date after or at the same date from the end date) and club the dates together according to the Customer and Period Columns. For example, for customer abc, the earliest start date is 29-Oct-16 and continues till 16-Jun-17, so we need this as one transaction in the output file. Then next transaction in output should be start date: 5-Dec-16 and end date:30-Mar-18 and so on.

The expected output would look something like:

```
Product_Name    Customer    Start_Date  End_Date    Period
      LP        abc         29-Oct-16   16-Jun-17   Monthly
      LP        abc         5-Dec-16    30-Mar-18   Monthly
      LP        abc         17-Oct-17   31-Dec-17   Monthly
      LP        abc         20-Oct-18   9-Mar-22    Monthly
      LP        xyz         7-Sep-15    14-Oct-16   Monthly
      LP        xyz         20-Oct-16   9-Mar-22    Monthly
      LP        xyz         20-Feb-17   22-Oct-18   Annual
```

I have tried with the following approch:

```
 df = Enhanced_Dataset.sort_values(['customer','Start_Date','Product_Name','Period'])
 day_diff = (df['Start_Date'] - df['End_Date'].groupby([df['customer'], df['Product_name'], df['Period']]).shift()).dt.days

 group_no = (day_diff.isna() | day_diff.gt(1)|day_diff.lt(-1)).cumsum()
 df_out = (df.groupby(['customer', group_no,'Product_Name','Period'], dropna=False, as_index=False)
        .agg({'customer': 'first',
              'Start_Date': 'first',
              'End_Date': lambda x: x.iloc[-1],
            }))
```

But getting the wrong result for example for customer abc as:

```
Product_Name    Period  customer    Start_date  End_Date
LP              Monthly abc     2016-10-29  2017-01-08  
LP              Monthly abc     2016-12-05  2017-08-31  
LP              Monthly abc     2017-01-07  2017-06-16  
LP              Monthly abc     2017-09-01  2018-03-30  
LP              Monthly abc     2017-10-17  2017-12-31  
LP              Monthly abc     2018-10-20  2022-03-09
```

in the above result it can be observe that  first row and third row is continuous and then second row and fourth row is continuous.
Can anyone help me to find what is wrong and how can i improve the code to get the expected out.

Comment: Give me a second, I wrote a function to deal with overlap like this. It's complicated and does use a loop, but it's logically sound.

Comment: In your row 3, the start date is 5-Dec-16 which is not one day within the end-date on previous row (8-Jan-17). Shouldn't they be different groups?

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure I understand why your output has as many rows as it does. For instance the 5-Dec-16 spell in the output is within the start of the spell above it? Why not just have 2 outputs for abc. Oct 29-2016 through March 30 2018 and October 18 2020 through March 9 2022. That is most normalized view you'd get after resolving all of the possible overlaps into unique spells.

Comment: I wanted to have the continous dates in a single transaction for start and end date.@ALollz

Comment: For example in the input df for customer abc in the first row the start date is 29 oct 2016 and end date is 3 Nov 2016 after that in the second row for the same customer abc it is continous as the start date is 2 Nov 2016 after that in the third row the start date is 5 Dec 2016 which is not continous as compared to the last end date which is in the second row i.e. 8Jan 2017 but fourth row is continous for the same customer as the start date is 7 Jan 2017.

Comment: after that there is no continuous dates for a the customer abc. Therefore, in the output there will be a sinlge transaction for customer abc with start date as 29 Oct 2016 and end date as 16 June 2017. @ALollz

Comment: Then will start with the transaction in df with start date as 5 Dec 2016 and check for the continous dates by comparing the last end date of the % Dec 2016 with the start date of other rows in order to evaluate the continous date to club the transcations with start and end date. @ALollz

Comment: @Mortz Yes correct.That is what we are expecting in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand you are trying to do is to take all pairs of transactions within a `['Customer', 'Product_Name', 'Period']` group and if the pairs satisfy the constraint that the `End_Date` of one member is within 1 day of `Start_Date` of the other member - we treat this pair of transactions as the same group.

In other words, you want to build a "graph" of transactions which you can do using `networkx`

The outline of the code is as follows -

1. Group by `['Customer', 'Product_Name', 'Period']`
2. Add each transaction within the group as a node to the Graph
3. Within each group construct all possible pairs (`itertools.combinations`)
4. Pairs that satisfy the 1-day constraint make edges with each other
5. Get the [nx.connected_components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))
6. Group by the component

```py
import networkx as nx
from datetime import timedelta
from itertools import combinations
from collections import namedtuple
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Customer', 'Product_Name', 'Period'])
trans_rec = namedtuple('trans_rec', ['idx', 'start_date', 'end_date'])
for group in df_grouped.groups:
    _transactions_df = df_grouped.get_group(group)
    _transactions = zip(_transactions_df.index, _transactions_df['Start_Date'], _transactions_df['End_Date'])
    G = nx.Graph()
    for _ in _transactions:
        G.add_node(trans_rec(*_))
    node_pairs = combinations(G.nodes, 2)
    for node_pair in node_pairs:
        node_1, node_2 = node_pair
        if timedelta(days=-1) <= node_2.end_date - node_1.start_date <= timedelta(days=1):
            G.add_edge(node_1, node_2)
        if timedelta(days=-1) <= node_1.end_date - node_2.start_date <= timedelta(days=1):
            G.add_edge(node_1, node_2)
    index_group_mapping = dict()
    for ix, cc in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)):
        for node in cc:
            index_group_mapping[node.idx] = '_'.join(group) + '_' + str(ix)
    _transactions_df['index_group'] = _transactions_df.index.map(index_group_mapping)
    agg_transactions = _transactions_df.groupby(['index_group']).agg({'Start_Date': 'min', 'End_Date': 'max'})
        agg_transactions = agg_transactions.reset_index()
        base_cols = agg_transactions.columns
        agg_transactions = agg_transactions.join(agg_transactions[
'index_group'].str.split('_', expand=True))
        new_cols = ['Customer', 'Product_Name', 'Period', 'group_num']
        agg_transactions.columns = list(base_cols) + list(new_cols)
        agg_transactions = agg_transactions[['Start_Date', 'End_Date', 'Customer', 'Product_Name', 'Period']]
        print(agg_transactions)


#   Start_Date   End_Date Customer Product_Name   Period
# 0 2016-10-29 2017-06-16      abc           LP  Monthly
# 1 2016-12-05 2018-03-30      abc           LP  Monthly
# 2 2017-10-17 2017-12-31      abc           LP  Monthly
# 3 2018-10-20 2022-03-09      abc           LP  Monthly
#   Start_Date   End_Date Customer Product_Name  Period
# 0 2017-10-20 2018-10-22      xyz           LP  Annual
#   Start_Date   End_Date Customer Product_Name   Period
# 0 2015-09-07 2016-10-14      xyz           LP  Monthly
# 1 2016-10-20 2022-03-09      xyz           LP  Monthly
```

Comment: Hey while running the above code getting an error@Mortz

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1776456876746702> in <module>
     16     for ix, cc in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)):
     17         for node in cc:
---> 18             index_group_mapping[node.idx] = '_'.join(group) + '_' + int(ix)
     19     _transactions_df['index_group'] = _transactions_df.index.map(index_group_mapping)
     20     print(_transactions_df.groupby(['index_group']).agg({'subs_in_date': 'min', 'subs_out_date': 'max'}))

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found @Mortz

Comment: tried with str as well still getting the same error

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1776456876746702> in <module>
     16     for ix, cc in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)):
     17         for node in cc:
---> 18             index_group_mapping[node.idx] = '_'.join(group) + '_' + str(ix)
     19     _transactions_df['index_group'] = _transactions_df.index.map(index_group_mapping)
     20     print(_transactions_df.groupby(['index_group']).agg({'subs_in_date': 'min', 'subs_out_date': 'max'}))

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Yes It worked. Customer was in int64 format converted to string. Now working fine. Thank you so much I would have not think of it without your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: One last question How to put the result in a dataframe

Comment: wanted to perform the script for big data around 80 lakh rows . It is taking more to run is there any anything we can do to reduce the running time @Mortz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242956/discussion-between-mortz-and-nikki).